# system overrides for session timeouts -- deprecated?

Tags: config, config-overrides

There's a note in the docs ([here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#expire-session-on-browser-close)) talking about cp_session_ttl and user_session_ttl overrides being replaced as part of the 2.8 update. But I can't see anything about it in the changelogs. Am I misunderstanding the note in the docs? Can somebody clarify this for me?

(I'm using those overrides as part of my MasterConfig setup and want to know if I should remove or change them).